# Confusion regarding definition of similar triangles.

Tags: geometry, logic, euclidean-geometry, definition

I am confused with the definition of similarity two triangles.My textbook defines similarity as follows:

1. corresponding angles are equal.
2. corresponding sides are in the same ratio.

My question is that do we need to state both $1$ and $2$ because I think they are equivalent,so saying one would suffice.
Can someone give a proof of their equivalence?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both definitions are necessary when defining similarity of two polygons. In the particular case of triangles, one can prove that weaker conditions are enough, called [similarity criteria](https://www.math-only-math.com/criteria-of-similarity-between-triangles.html). For two triangles, your conditions 1. and 2. correspond to AA and SSS criteria.

But similarity criteria are theorems, not definitions: most textbooks use for triangles the same definition of similarity valid for a generic polygon.